# My custom order by in criteria query/jpql

Tags: java, sql, jpql, criteria

Is it possible to do my custom order by using criteria query or jpql in Java? In my table, I have a column - number type(for now, this column includes numbers such as `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `10`). I would like to sort result in this order `2`, `5`, `1`, `10`, `3`.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyEntity> cq = cb.createQuery(MyEntity.class);
Root<MyEntity> root = cq.from(MyEntity.class);

cq.select(root);
cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("someMyFields"), "myExpectedFieldValue"));
cq.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get("myNumberField"))); // how can I sort result in this order 2, 5, 1, 10, 3?

TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.setFirstResult(0);
query.setMaxResults(200);

return query.getResultList();
```

How can I do it?

Comment: what logic is there? It's kinda random if you don't explain yourself

Comment: Whatever logic there is, the method cb.asc() accepts an expression, so if you implement your own logic inside `cb.asc()" you should be able to accomplish what you're asking for

Comment: In front-end, these numbers are assigned to the string value(for example: 2 - 'A', 5-'B', 1-'C', 10-'D', 3-'D'. I just would like to sort these values alphabetically.

Comment: Could you give me an example how i can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause to implement this kind of ["sort indirection"](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-implement-sort-indirection-in-sql/). In SQL and JPQL, this would be:

```sql
ORDER BY CASE myNumberField 
  WHEN 2  THEN 1
  WHEN 5  THEN 2
  WHEN 1  THEN 3
  WHEN 10 THEN 4
  WHEN 3  THEN 5
          ELSE 6
END
```

With the criteria API, using [`CriteriaBuilder.selectCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#selectCase-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression-)

```java
cq.orderBy(
  qb.selectCase(root.get("myNumberField"))
    .when(qb.literal(2), qb.literal(1))
    .when(qb.literal(5), qb.literal(2))
    .when(qb.literal(1), qb.literal(3))
    .when(qb.literal(10), qb.literal(4))
    .when(qb.literal(3), qb.literal(5))
    .otherwise(qb.literal(6))
    .getExpression()
    .asc());
```

Of course, a much better solution is to normalise these values in a separate table that you can join just for the ordering:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
JOIN orderings o ON t.myNumberField = o.myNumberField
ORDER BY o.orderDefinition
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom ordering with CriteriaQuery by using a special field in your database bean:

```
// this is used for obtaining an arbitrary ordering by statuses
@Formula(value="(CASE status\n" +
        "           WHEN 'DELETED'::text THEN 1\n" +
        "           WHEN 'UPDATED'::text THEN 2\n" +
        "           WHEN 'SUBMITTED'::text THEN 3\n" +
        "           ELSE 10\n" +
        "           END)")
private int statusPriority;
```

You can use the statusPriority as a regular sorting field through the Pagination object. The resulting query will contain something like:

```
order by (CASE quotationv0_.status
           WHEN 'DELETED'::text THEN 1
           WHEN 'UPDATED'::text THEN 2
           WHEN 'SUBMITTED'::text THEN 3
           ELSE 10
           END) asc
```