# Order query results with Criteria API by something that is NOT a database field

Tags: java, sql, criteria-api

I'm using Criteria API to fetch sorted data from my database.
Sorting like this works fine:

```
Path<Data> data = // initialize;
String sortField = // initialize name of field to sort by;
Expression<?> sortExpression = data.get(sortField);
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(sortExpression));
```

This way, I can order my results by field content. But how can I order by something else?

In my example, I have a database field `data.user_id` that contains a (nullable) user ID. While the query will fetch the ID, I want to sort not by the ID itself (the numerical value), but by the three categories "the ID is null", "the ID is mine", "the ID is someone elses". I have access to the ID that is "mine" in my service method, but how can I sort like that?

Comment: I think the only way to achieve these customs order by is to use "order by case". Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55807061/my-custom-order-by-in-criteria-query-jpql). Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, looking promising. I tried it but get a "ORA-00932 inconsistent datatypes: expected number got binary" error. My code looks like that: ```sortExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase(data.get("id"))
      .when(criteriaBuilder.literal(userId), criteriaBuilder.literal(1))
      .when(criteriaBuilder.nullLiteral(Long.class), criteriaBuilder.literal(2))
      .otherwise(criteriaBuilder.literal(3));``` where the ID is of type Long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work like this:

```
Expression<Long> id = data.get("userId");
Long userId = // ID of logged in user
Expression<?> sortExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
                        .when(criteriaBuilder.isNull(id), 1)
                        .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(id, userId), 2)
                        .otherwise(3);
```